# How to debug in Processing Development Environment (PDE), Also is there a plugin to support intellisense

Tags: processing

I am new to Processing development environment, I did my homework and all I found is to import processing libraries into Java IDE (eclipse) and use debugging, I am wondering if there is a PDE plugin that can help with intellisense and debugging as for small sketches PDE is very convenient.

Comment: I'm afraid not, using a dedicated Java IDE is your best bet. The closest thing is [this tool](https://github.com/Manindra29/Sketch-Outline) which just makes it easy to visualize and navigate sketch members but no debugging/autocompletion.

Comment: Thanks, I use Sketch-Outline, its a nice add-on for navigating through the types, I still miss intellisense and debug features, I ported my project to Eclipse and it is working fine so far.

Answer (score 10):

## Debugging

Since the launch of **Processing 3**, debugging is now a native feature of the Processing IDE.

In the screenshot below, you'll see a new `Debug` menu. I set breakpoints on the `setup()` and `draw()` methods as indicated by the `<>` marks in the line numbers. To the right is a popout window listing variable and object values, etc.

[image]

## Intellisense

From the Preferences menu, check the box **Code completion with Ctrl-space**.

[image]

Then, you can start typing a function like `ellipse` and press CTRL+Space to pop intellisense. Moreover, with that turned on, accessing properties or methods of an object by typing a `.` after should automatically pop intellisense.

## Using Another IDE

Finally, you could take advantage of a more powerful IDE by importing the processing core.jar into any Java project. The core.jar file is located relative to your Processing installation, such as:

OSX: `/Applications/Processing 3.0.1.app/Contents/Java/core/library/core.jar`
Windows: `\Program Files\processing-3.0.2\core\library\core.jar`

In Processing 1 and 2, this must be run as **Applet**. In Processing 3, run as **Java Application**. Here's an example to demonstrate:

```
import processing.core.*;

public class Main extends PApplet {

    // In Eclipse, run this project as Java Application (not Applet)
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"MAIN"};
        PApplet.runSketch(a, new Main());
    }

    public void settings() { // <-- that's different
        size(500, 500); // necessary here to prevent runtime IllegalStateException
    }

    public void setup() {
        // other one and done operations
    }

    public void draw() {
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 40, 40);
    }
}
```

Check out this post if you want to write Processing code in Eclipse across multiple classes.
https://processing.org/tutorials/eclipse/

Comment: This is a great step forward for processing. If there was a way to list, for a given breakpoint, your call stack, then the system would be super useful. As it is, I'll take the information here and try to plug in a full-featured IDE. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't get those features within the compact Processing development environment.

You can get autocompletion/intellisense with a decent Java IDE like IntelliJ or eclipse.
Personally I'm pretty happy with how the [Proclipsing](http://code.google.com/p/proclipsing/) eclipse plugin integrates with Processing (easy project export, library management, etc.)

Check out [this video guide](http://vimeo.com/19076476) on setting up:
[image: Proclipsing video snapshot]

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest Processing 2.0b7 version, and enable the 'EXPERIMENTAL' mode (top right corner), you have access to a small set of tools (breakpoints, step by step) and a realtime debugging console. It can't compare to other platforms such as VS or Eclipse, but it is a good start and gets some of the work done.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried, but for Processing 2.x there is [this](http://debug.martinleopold.com) tool for debugging. It has been discussed in [this topic](http://forum.processing.org/topic/gsoc-result-a-debug-mode-for-processing-2-0) in procesing forum.